# how to plott several curves after while loop in function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

```
def a(t, A, B, C, At, Bt):
  while:
    calculations
  return t, A, B, C, At, Bt
```

print(def(t, A, B, C, At, Bt))

I return several numpy.arrays. and wanna plot them in the form

```
B, = plt.plot(t, B)
C, = plt.plot(t, C) 
plt.legend(handles=[ B, C, A],
           labels=[ 'B', 'C', 'A'])
```

Comment: What is your exact question? Do you have some toy data to illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the object-oriented interface to matplotlib:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot
t, A, B, C, At, Bt = a(t, A, B, C, At, Bt)

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
for array, label in zip([A, B, C], ['A', 'B', 'C']):
    ax.plot(t, array, label=label)

ax.legend()
```

Comment: so I would need to write my funtion into a class? Because A, B, C, t, tend, ka, kb, At = a(A, B, C, t, tend, ka, kb, At) gives me not enough values to unpack

Comment: @pythonabsir In your question, as written, the function `a` return 6 values. In my answer, I unpack 6 values from the function `a`. It's up to you to return as many values as you need (or define them elsewhere)

Comment: y! I called a different number of values than I returned. thx got it!